# Im getting Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments error in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, error-handling

```
class RoomFeed: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
let posts = Post(id: self.documentId , author: owner!, text: text!, amount: self.amount)
```

```
//This is called in the view controller which is "host of table View" 
//Document Id at this point is not nill confirmed.


}





class PostTableVIewCell: UITableViewCell {
//This is table view cell

var king: String!
var postID: String!

 override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

    Firestore.firestore().collection("GeneralData").document("\(self.postID)").getDocument { document, err in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let data = document.data()
            self.king = data!["1"] as? String
            let placeamount = data!["amount"] as? String
            self.amountLabel.text = placeamount
    
        }
        print("KING: \(self.king!)")
        self.kingLabel.text = self.king
    }}

    func set(post:Post) {
         
            usernameLabel.text = post.author
            PostTextLabel.text = post.text
            self.amount = post.amount
          postID = post.id
        }
}
```

This is my code but I'm getting an error which states "'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments" what am I doing wrong?

[image: this is data structure]

Comment: Please, can you provide the firebase database structure?

Comment: Are you sure to pass the correct document ID? Are you sure it's not an optional?

Comment: Yeah I printed the document ID in the console before these lines of code and it printed the proper document ID

Comment: This is what the error more specifically says, "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'FIRESTORE INTERNAL ASSERTION FAILED: Invalid document reference. Document references must have an even number of segments, but GeneralData has 1'"

Comment: The code is well written, it should work. Try entering document ID manually. Remember that amount is a number, not a String. `let placeamount = data!["amount"] as? Int`

Comment: It appears you were right the post ID is in fact nil, This code is in a table view cell class, and I'm trying to transfer data from the Viewcontroller the table view is into the view cell right now I'm currently doing it through a class, which all my other values are transferring but for some reason not the document ID

Comment: Ok. If you need help, publish your full code.

Comment: Basically, when I get data from firebase such as the document Id I put it into the class, and then I tried to make the value of the documentId = to the post Id but it's showing as nill

Comment: I wrote you an answer. I had to slightly change the database structure for the example. In this way I believe you can better understand how firebase can be used.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably wrong approach. I wrote you an example code that might help you. Write me a comment if you need more help.

**ViewController.swift**

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    var postDataList = [Post]()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
    
        Firestore.firestore().collection("GeneralData").getDocuments { document, err in
            if let document = document {
                let dataDescription = document.documents
                    
                for i in dataDescription {
                    let post = Post.init(data: i.data())
                    self.postDataList.append(post)
                }
                
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
            else {
                print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }
    }
    
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.postDataList.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        
        let post = self.postDataList[indexPath.row]
        cell.setPost(post: post)
        
        return cell
    }
    
}
```

**CustomTableViewCell.swift**

```
import UIKit

class CustomTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var usernameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var postTextLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var amountLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func setPost(post: Post) {
        self.usernameLabel.text = post.name
        self.postTextLabel.text = post.text
        self.amountLabel.text = String(post.amount)
    }

}
```

**Post.swift**

```
struct Post {
    let name: String
    let surname: String
    let owner: String
    let amount: Int
    let text: String
    let uid: String
    
    init(data: [String: Any]) {
        self.name = data["name"] as! String
        self.surname = data["surname"] as! String
        self.owner = data["owner"] as! String
        self.amount = data["amount"] as! Int
        self.text = data["text"] as! String
        self.uid = data["uid"] as! String
    }
}
```

This is the structure your database should have:
[image]

Comment: I did what you said however I found out that the data was transferring but it appears the awakefromnib action is happening before the data transfer which is why its appears as nil so do you know how I can get around this?

Comment: If you followed exactly what I wrote to you it should work. Remember to use the same database structure. The cells will be updated after acquiring documents from the firestore.

Comment: The strings I want to be labels in the cell are working but the post id which in theory I want to be able to do print(postID) In the awake from nib func in the custom cell however when I do it, it shows nill. Could u edit in your code to show me how u would make the string from the view controller equal to a string in the customs cell rather string to label.

Comment: The ***getDocuments()*** method is a closures. So if you want to update the view of the ViewController you have to do it inside this method. For example, if you want to print Post IDs, you can do this by entering this `print("ID:", post.uid)` after `let post = Post.init(data: i.data())`.

Comment: I have edited your post in order to show you what I mean thanks for helping me though through this, I'm a beginner and I'm teaching myself so I'm not very good at explaining my code.

Comment: But essentially in my edit Im trying to print postID in the TableViewCell class not the view controller. Im. transferring the data through  the set post function but it shows up as nill

Comment: I can't approve your change because what you want to do is not correct. In awakeFromNib you cannot manage external objects. You should better explain what you really want to do, if you just want to print the postID you can add in the function `setPost (post: Post)` this code `print(post.uid)`. If you want more help, ask.

Comment: I want to have this in awake from nib:Firestore.firestore().collection("GeneralData").document("\(self.postID)").getDocument { document, err in
        if let document = document, document.exists {
            let data = document.data()
            self.king = data!["1"] as? String
            let placeamount = data!["amount"] as? String
            Self.amountLabel.text = placeamount
        self.kingLabel.text = self.king
    }}     //I need postID In this I order to get the specific document I'm looking for.

Comment: And if that line code cannot work in awake from nib is there another function I can put that code in which will be activated when the tableview cell loads?

Comment: I'll put in an edit on your post to show more accurately what I'm trying to do and if its wrong let me know

Comment: It is very wrong what you are trying to do. You should better study how UITableCell and UITableViewController work. If you want to process something you can do it in the `func setPost(post: Post)`, as I wrote above. The firebase methods are Closures. What you want to do has no correct logic. You should explain precisely what you want to accomplish in reality. If you already know the Post IDs, you can download them in the viewController or in the TableCell but you have to create a method for yourself. You can't do it in `awakeFromNib()`, it's not correct.

Comment: All I want to do is a when the user going to that view it goes in grabs the specific document using a posted and then displays a string within the document on the cell with a label of that makes sense.

Comment: If you draw me the UI on what you want to do I can help you. Give me an illustration of what you want to do, I can write you the code.

Comment: I tried sending you a photo but I don't have high enough reputation...But I'll try to explain it, essentially in the app I want there to be games, which are the table view cells and inside the cells it will display the players 1 and 2. However when I try to get the document for the specific post it doesn't work because the documentID is showing nil. And I want to do all of this including getting the specific document for the post in the table view cell class and do the labels their too is this possible?

Comment: You should only use the UITableCell class to set graphics. For data fetch you should build an external class.

Comment: I'm not too sure what that is could u show me what external class looks like